# If condition with date interval and dynamic year

Tags: php

I need a little help about a "if" condition in a specific period od the year. Cause I want to this once time forever the year myst be dynamic.
It will be like:

```
if (1 December of current year < $today > 8 january of next year)
```

I don't know how to do date's math for having the year that dynamically changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kreker, my good man, use Or instead of And:

```
if ((strtotime("1 December") < time()) || (time() < (strtotime("8 January"))))
{
    echo "Yip!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strtotime("1 December") < time() > strtotime("8 January next year"))
```

Comment: It's not correct! Why you vote this answer without knowing if it's working?? There is a syntax error, you can't comparion with 2 logical operator in php...needs some braket. The other error is the same sa mine. If you put "next year" and for example we are on 4 january 2011, when you make the comparsion it make with 8 january 2012....so it doesn't work!!

Comment: @Kreker, you are really something else! Somebody is trying to help and you shout at them like this?

Comment: @kreker about other error, you asc about 1 Dec and 8 jan next year. strtotime functions are work correctly for this dates.